# Is there any other way to extract the number of exam?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, phpmyadmin

Hello everyone I have a problem that I need help with I'm trying to get number of exam for specified student

we have three tables :

```
etudient (N_Appoge,Nom,PRENOM,filiere,....)

module (NUM_Module,Nom_module,Nom_semestre)

Inscrit (N_Appoge,NUM_Module) // this table is the relation between etudiant & module
```

so basically students with the same class means they have the same filiere and the same Nom_semestre

I tried this query :

```
set @num_exam=0;
SELECT DISTINCT N_APPOGE, NOM, PRENOM, filiere,Nom_semestre,
(@num_exam:=@num_exam+1) as num_exam FROM etudiant,
module 
WHERE 
  filiere in (SELECT filiere FROM etudiant WHERE N_APPOGE='1610065' ) 
  And 
  Nom_semestre In 
    (SELECT Nom_semestre from module WHERE Nom_semestre='s1' 
    and NUM_module in (SELECT NUM_module from inscrit where N_APPOGE='1610065')) 
ORDER by NOM;
```

but the result was not like I expected it shows two result of the same student with `N_APPOGE='1610065'` and multiple result for other student as well

It looks like DISTINCT in this case does not work what's the solution here ?

Comment: This is not Oracle code.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult to be certain that a proposed answer is correct without test data. Please edit your question (using the `edit` button just below the tags) and include samples of data for all of the tables in your question so that the problem can be reproduced. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a join between `etudiant` and `module`, but in the `WHERE` clause there is nothing which specifies how these two tables are related. As such, the database is performing a cross join (each row in the first table is joined to each row in the second table). Apparently you need to get the table `inscrit` involved:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.N_APPOGE,
                e.NOM,
                e.PRENOM,
                e.filiere,
                m.Nom_semestre,
                (@num_exam:=@num_exam+1) as num_exam
  FROM etudiant e
  INNER JOIN inscrit i
    ON i.N_Appoge = e.N_Appoge
  INNER JOIN module m
    ON m.NUM_Module = i.NUM_Module
  WHERE e.filiere in (SELECT filiere
                       FROM etudiant
                       WHERE N_APPOGE='1610065') And 
        m.Nom_semestre In (SELECT Nom_semestre
                             from module
                             WHERE Nom_semestre='s1' and
                                   NUM_module in (SELECT NUM_module
                                                    from inscrit
                                                    where N_APPOGE='1610065')) 
  ORDER by NOM
```

Hopefully that will help.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer , the query work perfectly but what if I want to select Num_exam ( for example the student with N_appoge = 1610065) and show the result 
using Php ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Php so I can't address that for you. Your best bet is to ask another question.

Comment: Thanks man , I found the solution to this . So much respect for you man

Comment: there is still a problem with the query that I didn't notice until today it still gives repeated names for example the student with `N_appoge=1610065` it repeats couple of times or more that depends on `table inscrit` because we can find in inscrit the same N_appoge with different `NUM_Module` how can I fix this @Bob

Comment: Drop the `(@num_exam:=@num_exam+1) as num_exam` and see if that gets it. You might try asking another question, and include test data and expected results so people who post answers can verify that their query provides the results you expected. Thanks.

Comment: I can't drop it if I do it won't be other column to extract number of exam , I once forgot to use `Set @num_exam=0;` then it gave a table of students without repeating but the extra column that can hold number of exam is empty , if there is another way around this maybe ? Thanks @Bob